# Is pinch zoom supported in CreateJS?

Tags: createjs

Is the pinch zoom touch gesture supported in CreateJS? I can not find anything in the [docs](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Touch.html).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no native support for gestures but once you [enable it](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Touch.html#method_enable) touch events are translated into mouse events and identified by [pointerID](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/MouseEvent.html#property_pointerID) property. Based on this I have been able implemented the pinch zoom gesture in my project (though I have not tested it beyond latest Android.)

This is a snippet from my project:

```
stage.on("mousedown", function (evt : createjs.MouseEvent) {
    if (evt.pointerID == 0 || evt.pointerID == -1) { //touch 1 or mouse
        touch1 = new createjs.Point(stage.globalToLocal(evt.stageX, 0).x, stage.globalToLocal(0, evt.stageY).y);
    } else if (evt.pointerID == 1) { //touch 2
        touch2 = new createjs.Point(stage.globalToLocal(evt.stageX, 0).x, stage.globalToLocal(0, evt.stageY).y);
    }
});

stage.on("pressup", function (evt : createjs.MouseEvent) {
    if (evt.pointerID == 0 || evt.pointerID == -1) { //touch 1 or mouse
        touch1 = null;
    } else if (evt.pointerID == 1) { //touch 2
        touch2 = null;
    }
});

stage.on("pressmove", function(evt : createjs.MouseEvent) {
    if (evt.pointerID == -1 || evt.pointerID == 0) {
        var touch = touch1;
    } else if (evt.pointerID == 1) {
        var touch = touch2;
    }

    var dX = stage.globalToLocal(evt.stageX, 0).x - touch.x;
    var dY = stage.globalToLocal(0, evt.stageY).y - touch.y;

    if (touch1 && touch2) var oldDist = distanceP(touch1, touch2);

    touch.x += dX;
    touch.y += dY;

    //if both fingers are used zoom and move the canvas
    if (touch1 && touch2) {
        var newDist = distanceP(touch1, touch2);
        var newZoom = zoom * newDist / oldDist;
        zoomMap(newZoom, new createjs.Point((touch1.x+touch2.x)/2, (touch1.y + touch2.y)/2))

        //if both fingers are used apply only half of the motion to each of them
        dX /= 2;
        dY /= 2;
    }

    map.x += dX;
    map.y += dY;

    stage.update();
});

function distanceP(p1 : createjs.Point, p2 : createjs.Point) : number {
    return Math.sqrt((p2.x-p1.x)*(p2.x-p1.x) + (p2.y-p1.y)*(p2.y-p1.y));
}

function zoomMap(newZoom : number, zoomCenter : createjs.Point) {
    ....
}
```

NOTE: I am moving and zooming DO called Map. The stage itself is zoomed due to various devicePixelRatio's (retina display etc), that's why the use of globalToLocal functions.

Answer (score 1):

No. EaselJS handles normal mouse events (to determine what is clicked), as well as some drag events, since determining a drag target is a common usage. Additionally, touch events are translated into mouse events (including multi-touch).

Things like swipe, pinch, and other gestures are not handled by the framework at this time.

Comment: In that case I will be able to build the pinch zoom detection, only question is HOW EXACTLY are touch events are translated into mouse events? How do I recognise the second touch and distinguish between moves of the two fingers? Thanks

Comment: Check out the ui/Touch class. It passes the touch ID into the stage, which is then dispatched with a MouseEvent. MouseEvent contains a nativeEvent, pointerID, and indicates whether it is the primary (mouse) pointer. http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/MouseEvent.html